# About how to change the policy urls of "Google Apps Marketplace SDK"

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have a question. Let's Say:

I try to change the URL of "Privacy Policy URL" and "Term of Service URL" on the configuration page of Google Apps Marketplace SDK.

- The configuration URL
  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket_component/googleapps_sdk?project=

But The URL value is not changed though I input a new URL and push the button "Save".
I can change the values of other columns, "SetUp URL", "Support URL", etc.
Only below two URLs cannot be changed...

Could you tell me how to change bellow urls of "Google Apps Marketplace SDK"?

Best regard.